# BUT051 table is not updated with BUR_BUPR_BUT051_COLLECT

Tags: abap, sap-crm

I'm trying to update DB Table `BUT051` by using function module `BUR_BUPR_BUT051_COLLECT`.

The problem is that it doesn't update at all.

Here's part of my code I'm currently using to update `BUT051`.
Note: The field I'm trying to update is `BUT051~PARTNER1`.

```
FORM update_but051.

  "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
  " TABLES
  "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
  DATA: lt_but051 TYPE TABLE OF but051.

  "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
  " STRUCTURES
  "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
  DATA: ls_but051 TYPE but051.

  REFRESH: lt_but051.
  CLEAR: ls_but051.

  " Getting all relationships of the given accounts/partners
  SELECT * FROM but051 INTO TABLE lt_but051 WHERE partner1 IN lt_partners_so.

  " Replacing all partners(field `partner1`) with the master partner.
  ls_but051-partner1 = p_mstcln.
  MODIFY lt_but051 FROM ls_but051 TRANSPORTING partner1 WHERE partner1 <> p_mstcln.

  CLEAR: ls_but051.

  LOOP AT lt_but051 INTO ls_but051.

     CALL FUNCTION 'BUR_BUPR_BUT051_COLLECT'
      EXPORTING
        i_subname = 'BUT051'
        i_but051  = ls_but051.
  ENDLOOP.

  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
    EXPORTING
      wait = abap_true.

ENDFORM.
```

Few notes on this code:

- Variable `p_mstcln` is a parameter of type `c(10)`, this is the new partner number.
- Internal Table `lt_partners_so` is a table of partners all of which need to be replaced by `p_mstcln` in `but051`.

Am I using the right function?

Is there another Function Module that does what I want to(updating the field `partner1` in `but051`)?

Comment: Have you looked inside the FM you’re calling?  It does not update or insert anything to the database.  I don’t know what the right method is to update that table, but this FM is not it.

Comment: @BryanCain I did not look inside the function. But I found a question on the SAP forum which tells that this is the function to update table `BUT051`. Do you happen to know what function should I use?

Comment: package BUPA has a number of function modules that might help you. BAPI_BUPR_CONTP_CHANGE sounds like it might be what you're looking for. There are others to delete or create relationships between partners as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BUT051 is a table for Business Partner relationships and SAP has a special note for this:

[2594686 - Mass update relationships for BP](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002594686)

which advises to use the following Function Modules for updating relationships:

- BAPI_BUPR_RELATIONSHIP_CHANGE
- BAPI_BUPR_RELATIONSHIP_CREATE
- BAPI_BUPR_RELATIONSHIP_DELETE
- BAPI_BUPR_RELATIONSHIP_GET
- BAPI_BUPR_RELATIONSHIP_REMOVE
- BAPI_BUPR_RELSHIP_CHECKEXIST
- BAPI_BUPR_RELSHIP_GET_DETAIL